# How to stop submit button from expanding along with textarea?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form action="" class="d-flex">
  <textarea name="post_text" class="form-control"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

When I expand the textarea, the submit button also expands. How can I stop the button from expanding? Only the textarea should expand, not the button

Comment: Post your css as well, html is useless without css in your question.

Comment: There is no extra css involved. Except for those applied via bootstrap

Comment: Code snippets allow you to link external libraries, so you could link `bootstrap` to your code and we would see the problem.

Comment: Why don't you set `max-height` property for `textarea` and put a `div` for  `submit` button?

Comment: I just provided a solution with Bootstrap (according the edit) and I inserted it in my answer, however I decided to leave both the solutions (with and without Bootstrap inclusion)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Bootstrap documentation, you can see that you need to put your form tags inside `form-group`:

```
<form action="" class="d-flex">
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="post_text" class="form-control"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will only push vertically, if you don't want it to push anywhere, you have to set a height for textarea and disable resizing option using css.

```css
.formAction {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="formAction">
      <textarea name="post_text" class="form-control"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

**Solution without BootStrap:** This solution allow the Submit `button` to be under the `textarea` and also is structured to have max and min bounds about `textarea`.

```css
.form-control {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="d-flex">
  <textarea name="post_text" class="form-control"></textarea>
  <div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  </div>
</form>
```

**Edit according with Bootstrap inclusion:** I used to put a `div` inside the form with class `.row`, then I used `bs-linebreak` combined with `col-md-12` as classes to make Submit button under the `textarea`.
-> **Notice:** `textarea` `div` class can be omitted.

```css
.form-control {
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form action="" class="d-flex">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <textarea name="post_text" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 bs-linebreak">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```